# Android, httpclient, как получить ответ от сервера?

Tags: java, android-studio, http, post, httpclient

Половина кода писал не я(не пинайте, в java я новичок, а в android подавно), а находил из примеров, в результате чего, получилось (вроде) составить запрос на сервер, но вот проблема, мне нужен токен, для этого я должен получить ответ от сервера. Вроде бы делал все, как многие, но что то я намудрил явно.

```
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {


        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // replace with your url
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://ololo.ru/login");


        //Post Data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "padavan"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "123123123"));


        //Encoding POST data
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //making POST request.

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // write response to log


    }
};
```

UPD: ошибочка, понял что с таким кодом, ответ я врятли получу (сервер присылает ответ в json). Подскажите, как мне переделать код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался сам :) , привожу код, для других:

```
try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            Log.d(TAG, "done");

            String bTime = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
            Log.d(TAG, bTime);
            Log.d(TAG, "УРААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААААА");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```